# Using an echo within an echo PHP

Tags: php, string, echo

In PHP is it possible to use site_url within an echo statement that already contains text? For instance could i change:

```
$data['following'] = 'You are not following ' . $name . ' <a href="http://raptor.kent.ac.uk/proj/co539/microblog/jlo21/index.php/user/follow/' . $name . ' ">Follow this user</a>';
```

to

```
$data['following'] = 'You are not following ' . $name . ' <a href="<?php echo site_url("user/follow"); ?>">Follow this user</a>
```

Comment: No. But you could use string concatenation just like you did with `$name`.

Answer (score 1):

No, but why not just concatenate the return value instead of trying to `echo` it?

```
$data['following'] = 'You are not following ' . $name . ' <a href="' . site_url("user/follow") . '">Follow this user</a>
```

Comment: Ah, I see thank you for the simple explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['following'] = 'You are not following ' . $name . ' <a href="' . site_url("user/follow") . '">Follow this user</a>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function call inside a string concatenation:

```
$data['following'] = 'You are not following ' . $name . ' <a href="'. site_url("user/follow") . '">Follow this user</a>';
```

The function will return the string and it will be concatenated like a variable would.